# Array formula in googlesheets being errored out by new row

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am using the array formula below to apply the same formula to new rows when they are added. However, when new rows are added, it messes up the formula (I think it is autocorrecting, or something). I went to Tools and turned off all autocomplete functions. Does anyone know what could be happening?

The formula I am using:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C),IF(C2:C<TODAY(),1,0),))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "messes up the formula"?

Answer (score 1):

try to freeze it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(INDIRECT("C2:C")),IF(INDIRECT("C2:C")<TODAY(),1,0),))
```

or if this is a form sheet use this formula in row 1:

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C),IF(C2:C<TODAY(),1,0),))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a "false" case in the outer IF statement.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C),IF(C2:C<TODAY(),1,0),**missing**))
```

Also I don't think you can use a column for the `len()` function.  I'm not sure what the context of this formula is but I suggest trying to remove the `ARRAYFORMULA()` like so:

```
IF(LEN(C1),IF(C1<TODAY(),1,0),**some false case**)
```

Comment: The `len()` function works fine in an array formula that iterates an open-ended range, and will give row-by-row results. Using a copy-down formula may solve the the issue provided that the issue is with values being manually entered in the formula column, but it is currently unclear whether that is what is being asked.